# Unable to uninstall Python 3.5 on Windows

Tags: windows, python3

I am trying to uninstall Windows 64-bit Python version on my Windows 7 laptop, but unable to do so.

It detects an installed version so it provides the option to modify, repair or uninstall. But on initializing uninstall it says:

> No Python 3.5 installation was detected.

I have tried doing a repair and then uninstall but to no avail. I have also tried several solutions mentioned online but nothing works.

Following is the log:

```
[0130:32A4][2018-08-28T12:57:42]i360: Creating a system restore point.
[0130:32A4][2018-08-28T12:57:54]i361: Created a system restore point.
[410C:17CC][2018-08-28T12:57:54]i371: Updating session, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{e599f76f-2b95-44da-a280-77548b1b2a21}, resume: Active, restart initiated: No, disable resume: No
[410C:17CC][2018-08-28T12:57:54]i329: Removed package dependency provider: {810503AC-4E50-4A21-BD5A-BFA973480B35}, package: path_JustForMe
[410C:17CC][2018-08-28T12:57:54]i326: Removed dependency: {e599f76f-2b95-44da-a280-77548b1b2a21} on package provider: {6ADAF31E-EEE6-4251-BE5A-EFD7868D3930}, package pip_JustForMe
[410C:17CC][2018-08-28T12:57:54]i329: Removed package dependency provider: {6ADAF31E-EEE6-4251-BE5A-EFD7868D3930}, package: pip_JustForMe
[410C:17CC][2018-08-28T12:57:54]i301: Applying execute package: pip_JustForMe, action: Uninstall, path: (null), arguments: ' ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT="1" MSIFASTINSTALL="7" TARGETDIR="C:\Users\gjoshi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\" OPTIONALFEATURESREGISTRYKEY="Software\Python\PythonCore\3.5\InstalledFeatures"'
[410C:17CC][2018-08-28T12:57:58]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to uninstall MSI package.
[410C:17CC][2018-08-28T12:57:58]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to configure per-user MSI package.
[410C:17CC][2018-08-28T12:57:58]i319: Applied execute package: pip_JustForMe, result: 0x80070643, restart: None
[410C:17CC][2018-08-28T12:57:58]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to execute MSI package.
[410C:17CC][2018-08-28T12:57:58]i318: Skipped rollback of package: pip_JustForMe, action: Install, already: Present
[410C:17CC][2018-08-28T12:57:58]i319: Applied rollback package: pip_JustForMe, result: 0x0, restart: None
[410C:17CC][2018-08-28T12:57:58]i323: Registering package dependency provider: {6ADAF31E-EEE6-4251-BE5A-EFD7868D3930}, version: 3.5.150.0, package: pip_JustForMe
[410C:17CC][2018-08-28T12:57:58]i325: Registering dependency: {e599f76f-2b95-44da-a280-77548b1b2a21} on package provider: {6ADAF31E-EEE6-4251-BE5A-EFD7868D3930}, package: pip_JustForMe
[410C:17CC][2018-08-28T12:57:58]i372: Session end, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{e599f76f-2b95-44da-a280-77548b1b2a21}, resume: ARP, restart: None, disable resume: No
[410C:17CC][2018-08-28T12:57:58]i371: Updating session, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{e599f76f-2b95-44da-a280-77548b1b2a21}, resume: ARP, restart initiated: No, disable resume: No
[410C:17CC][2018-08-28T12:57:58]i399: Apply complete, result: 0x80070643, restart: None, ba requested restart:  No
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution that worked was clicking repair from the installer and let it fail.
After it failed, I uninstalled it and re-installed it and it worked fine.

All steps done through the standard installer.